# How to make image within json draggable and allow drop in specific location?

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm trying to build a basic card matching game template where you can match the picture with the word and also allow the users to change the image and the word within the json file. However, I'm trying to make each of the image draggable and allow it to be dropped within the box. I have written the functions to drag and drop, but I dont know how to implement it to the image or the box. (Also, I apologise for keeping it the html, css and javascript within one script).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p> game project </p>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <style>
    .image {
      float: right;
      width: 250px;
      height: 146.5px;
    }
      
    .box {
      float: bottom;
      width: 260px;
      height: 176.5px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>


  <script>
    var gameData = [{
        box: "one",
        image: "https://techflourish.com/images/number-1-clipart-png-24.jpg"
      },
      {
        box: "four",
        image: "https://www.merlinmotorsport.co.uk/files/resized/large/R/img/rn_9_4.jpg?cachebreak=e8704429f3846f8e7d7c14b2ec72d306"
      },
      {
        box: "nine",
        image: "https://kingfisher.scene7.com/is/image/Kingfisher/5020657994625_01c"
      },
    ];


    function drag001(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("choice001", event.target.id);
    }

    function drag002(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("choice002", event.target.id);
    }

    function drag003(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("choice003", event.target.id);
    }

    //allows images to be dropped within the boxes
    function allowDrop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }


    function drop001(event) {
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("choice001");
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      score.innerHTML = i++;

    }

    function drop002(event) {
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("choice002");
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      score.innerHTML = i++;

    }

    function drop003(event) {
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("choice003");
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      score.innerHTML = i++;

    }

    function gameTemplate(game) {
      return `
       <img class="image" src ="${game.image}">
       <p class ="box">${game.box}</p>
      `
    }

    //displays the image and box localhost
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
    <h1>image ${gameData.length} results</h1>
    ${gameData.map(gameTemplate).join('')}
    `

    /* $(document).ready(function(){
          var imageData = [
       {"image":"/FYP/Images/Number1.jpg"},
       {"image2":"/FYP/Images/Number4.jpg"},
       {"image3":"/FYP/Images/Number9.jpg"},

       ];
       $.each(imageData, function (index, value) {
       $("#number").append("<img src='"+value.image+ "' />")
       });

     }); */
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p> game project </p>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <style>
    .image {
      float: right;
      width: 250px;
      height: 146.5px;
    }

    .box {
      float: bottom;
      width: 260px;
      height: 176.5px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>


  <script>
    var gameData = [{
        box: "one",
        image: "/FYP/Images/Number1.jpg"
      },
      {
        box: "four",
        image: "/FYP/Images/Number4.jpg"
      },
      {
        box: "nine",
        image: "/FYP/Images/Number9.jpg"
      },
    ];


    function drag001(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("choice001", event.target.id);
    }

    function drag002(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("choice002", event.target.id);
    }

    function drag003(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("choice003", event.target.id);
    }

    //allows images to be dropped within the boxes
    function allowDrop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }


    function drop001(event) {
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("choice001");
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      score.innerHTML = i++;

    }

    function drop002(event) {
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("choice002");
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      score.innerHTML = i++;

    }

    function drop003(event) {
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("choice003");
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      score.innerHTML = i++;

    }

    function gameTemplate(game) {
      return `
       <img class="image" src ="${game.image}">
       <p class ="box">${game.box}</p>
      `
    }

    //displays the image and box localhost
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
    <h1>image ${gameData.length} results</h1>
    ${gameData.map(gameTemplate).join('')}
    `

    /* $(document).ready(function(){
          var imageData = [
       {"image":"/FYP/Images/Number1.jpg"},
       {"image2":"/FYP/Images/Number4.jpg"},
       {"image3":"/FYP/Images/Number9.jpg"},

       ];
       $.each(imageData, function (index, value) {
       $("#number").append("<img src='"+value.image+ "' />")
       });

     }); */
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be easier to use a drag/drop library, https://shopify.github.io/draggable/

Comment: You'll have to get really familiar with `MouseEvent` triggers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent . Like @Atav32 said it might be simpler to build upon the work of others.